# EF codefirst : How do i make an 1:many (uniDirectional)relation cascade on delete

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

Here is my models :

```
public  class User
{
    public int     UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }
}
public class Shipment
{
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public int UserId {get; set;} 
}
```

Any User May have 0~many shipments.I want to casccade the corresponded shipments and delete them automaticly when i delete  an user.
I dont want make the relation BiDirrectional.and eneable DeleteOnCascade from other side by make the Virtual User Property [Requierd].
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the above by overriding 'OnModelCreating' as follows.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Shipments).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RossCyrus Can you explain in more detail what happens when you implement the above solution as it should work.